# how to use pregmatch to prevent repeated characters (arabic encoding)?

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, preg-match, arabic

```php
if (preg_match('/(\w)\1{2,}/', utf8_decode($name)))
    return t('3 Repeated charachter Are not allowed');
```

works fine to prevent latin charaters from repeating more than 2 times in a row ..

the problem is that code don't work with arabic encoding >> plz help fox.. and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to add the u modifier at the end of the pattern:

```
if (preg_match('/(\w)\1{2,}/u', $name))
    return t('3 Repeated charachter Are not allowed')
```

The u modifier change the meaning of the `\w` character class. By default, the `\w` character class stands for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` but with the u modifier, it becomes `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`.

In other words, it contains all unicode letters, digits and the underscore.

The u modifier forces too the regex engine to treat the pattern string as an unicode string.